# I am looking for a solution on the issue(org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Iface) while connecting talend open studio with hive

Tags: hive, talend

i am facing this issue while connecting talend open studio with hive. Below is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface  at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   mtn_project.hive_test_0_1.hive_test.tHiveConnection_1Process(hive_test.java:353)
>     at
>   mtn_project.hive_test_0_1.hive_test.runJobInTOS(hive_test.java:674)
>     at mtn_project.hive_test_0_1.hive_test.main(hive_test.java:523)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Iface  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>   [statistics] disconnected     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 6 more

Comment: this issue is with your port you are connecting to. could you please verify it once

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` usually indicates that certain libraries in your environment are missing.

See for example [Connect Hive thorugh Java JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760141/connect-hive-thorugh-java-jdbc)

In your case it might be a possibility that you need the Big Data edition.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message and using following jars helped me.
They're located in the $SPARK_HOME/jars folder:

```
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar  
hadoop-common-3.0.0.jar     
hive-jdbc-1.2.1.spark2.jar  
hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar  
httpclient-4.5.2.jar  
libthrift-0.9.3.jar
guava-14.0.1.jar           
hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar  
hive-service-1.2.2.jar           
httpcore-4.4.4.jar
```